# The definition of simple eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

There seem to be two accepted definitions for simple eigenvalues. The definitions involve algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity. When space has a finite dimension, the most used is algebraic multiplicity. As I am interested in the general case (where the dimension of space can be infinite) I will not speak of the characteristic polynomial.

Let $E$ be a Banach space (possible infinite) and $A:E\to E$ a linear operator, then the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is **simple** if

1. The dimension of $\mathcal{N}_{\lambda}=\cup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{N}((\lambda I-A)^k)$ is $1$ -- algebraic multiplicity $m_a(\lambda)=1$; or
2. The dimension of $\mathcal{N}(\lambda I - A)$ is $1$ -- geometric multiplicity $m_g(\lambda)=1$.

Note that the definitions are not equivalent as we have $m_a \ge m_g$. We have that, if an eigenvalue is simple in definition 1, it will be simple in definition 2, but the opposite is not true.

As mentioned in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2384999/680679), in ergodic theory definition 2 is used. In this case, why is this definition used? Is there a range of *useful* operators they want to include using this definition?

More precisely, I am interested in the difference when we characterize [ergodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity#Formal_definition). A system is ergodic iff 1 is a simple eigenvalue of the [Koopman operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_operator). See [question 4](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Eclimenha/2017-spring-7326/hw-3.pdf) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1778237/680679). Another moment where the simplicity of the eigenvalue appears is in the Perron-Frobenius theorem ([finite version](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ruelle-Perron-Frobenius_Theorem)).

In this context of ergodic theory (mainly, speaking of the Koopman operator), I was told that the definitions are equivalent, but I was not convinced by the explanation.

---

$\mathcal{N}(X)$ is the kernel or nullpace of $X$.

Comment: "why is this the definition used"? well, as said in my question, you get clean statements like ergodicity being equivalent to $1$ being a simple eigenvalue of the unitary operator.

Comment: @mathworker21 Okay, but I was wondering, how does a map "behave" as the unitary operator with 1 being a simple eigenvalue (in definition 1)? I mean, what kind of maps would we be "missing" using definition 1?

Comment: Consider the two matrices $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} \mu & \\ & \lambda \end{pmatrix}$ with $\lambda \neq \mu$. Both have a $\lambda$-eigenspace of dimension 1, but the first has a generalised $\lambda$-eigenspace of dimension 2. The nice thing about eigenspaces is that by just knowing the space and the scalar you can determine the action of the matrix; the nasty thing about generalised eigenspaces is that you need to know more: the operator may do something nontrivial on the generalised eigenspace.